# Difference between SOM and Hopfield

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, networks, self-organizing-maps

I am learning about [SOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map) and also about [Hopfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network) networks.
I yet don't understand why I would use `SOM` over `Hopfield` and vice versa.

What kind of problems I should resolve with SOM and which with Hopfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with SOMs, but not with Hopfield networks. A quick glance at Wikipedia says that Hopfield networks are used for associative memory, while SOMs are used for dimensionality reduction.

So SOMs are used to visualize high-dimensional data and for clustering high-dimensional data, if the data actually lies on a low (2D usually) manifold in a high-dimensional space. SOMs incorporate a (usually) 2D neighbor-defining grid which is how it does what it does, and at least according to Wikipedia this feature is unique among ANNs.

I guess Hopfield networks could be used for some kind of classification, but their main use would be something more like a robust, approximate value-value kind of lookup. Someone who knows them better could give a better answer.

EDIT: To correct the points addressed by alto's comment.

Comment: Since Hopfield networks are autoassociative it's more useful to think of them as a value-value lookup rather than a key-value lookup, which would be heteroassociative. They can be used for denoising, filling in missing variables, or even approximately solving hard optimization problems (like TSP). I also wouldn't say SOMs are for classification (unless you would say k-means is for classification, which I definitely would not).